# When talking about terms it should be with an article (a/an) before the term?

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article

When talking about terms it should be with article (a/an) before the term? 
For example:

1 What is *an* urticaria?

or

2 What is urticaria?

Thanks!

Comment: Note, because [urticaria](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/urticaria) begins with a vowel *sound*, you would use *an* urticaria. Except that since it is an uncountable or mass noun, you would usually not use the indefinite article before it.

Comment: If you say "What does *urticaria* mean?", then you don't need an article even if it is a count noun.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the word you are asking about.

You would not use an article if you are asking about

- A [mass noun](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/massnounterm.htm)

  > "What is spaghetti?"
- A proper noun, or a name.

  > "What is 'The New York Times'?"
- A plural noun.

  > "What **are** fish?" or "What **is a** fish?"

In every other context, you would use an article.

As for the example you gave, "urticaria" is a mass noun, so you should say:

> "What is urticaria?"

Comment: [Urticaria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urticaria) would be "What **is** urticaria". It's an ailment and is singular.  Even "[hives](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hives-and-angioedema/basics/definition/con-20014815)", though plural sounding, **should** get the singular. See the first sentence of the Wikipedia article: "Urticaria [...] commonly referred to as hives, ***is*** a kind of skin rash notable for pale red, raised, itchy bumps."

Comment: Oh, okay, I will edit that in.

Comment: @Catija Some dictionaries call *hives* a 'plural noun' while others just say it can take either a singular or plural verb. See [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hives) and [One Look](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Hives&ls=a)

Comment: Thank you. What is "mass noun"?

Comment: There is a link in my answer. A mass noun is any noun that you can't count, for example water, or grass. You cannot say "I have three water"

Answer (score 0):

If you have never heard the word urticaria, you simply ask: What is urticaria. It is totally irrelevant whether it is a mass noun or not, or a term or not. You don't know the word, so you don't know what kind of word it is.